# Umbraco - LogOut Backoffie user in umbracoApiController

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, umbraco8

i am having an issue with logging out a Backoffice user.

The usecase is that i am manually logging out the user by setting the users jwt token expiration day to now, and then i would like to log out the user from the umbraco backoffice if logged in.

Below is the code for my logout method.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("logout")]
public void LogOut()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["token"].Expires = DateTime.Now;
    Members.Logout();
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}
```

The User remains signed into the backoffice. Is there anyone that can help me with signing the user out of the backoffice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your post you are talking about logging out of the back office, while using the `Members.Logout()` which is for the members.

To log out backoffice users you need to use the `UserService`

I have tested it and if you know the userID then you can use the

```
Services.UserService.ClearLoginSessions(int userID)
```

To find the userID you could use the

```
Services.UserService.GetByUsername(string username)
```

method. (But maybe there is a better option in your case.)

[More information about UserService](https://our.umbraco.com/apidocs/v8/csharp/api/Umbraco.Core.Services.IUserService.html)

Comment: Thank you Dharman "Services.UserService.ClearLoginSessions(int userID)", solved it :)